# Sort array and arrange on the basis of some value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
 [Defense] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => G 
                [point] => 1.6

            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => F 
                [point] => 2.7
            )


        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => C 
                [point] => 1.4
            )
        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [position] => C 
                [point] => 1.7
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [position] => D 
                [point] => 1.1
            )
        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => F 
                [point] => 1.7
            ) 

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => G 
                [point] => 1.6

            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [position] => G 
                [point] => 1.8

            )
       [8] => stdClass Object
        (
                [id] => 2
                [position] => D
                [point] => 1.5
        )   
  )
```

I want to sort the array on the basis of point `descending` in `PHP`. Also, all the position come in sequence (all `G` than all `F` so on..)
like this:

```
  [Defense] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => G 
                    [point] => 1.8

                )
             [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => G 
                    [point] => 1.6

                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => G 
                    [point] => 1.6

                )   
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => F 
                    [point] => 2.7
                )
            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => F 
                    [point] => 1.7
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [position] => C 
                    [point] => 1.7
                )
            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [position] => C 
                    [point] => 1.4 
                )
            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [position] => D
                    [point] => 1.5
                )
            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [position] => D 
                    [point] => 1.1
                )

      )
```

Any help?

Comment: I'd say take a look at phps array sorting functions: `usort()` or `uasort()`.

Comment: Build a logic of sorting algo or  use Built in array sorting function. Pass your arrays" point or position" variable in sorting function and they will be sorted accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use usort() function to sort the array as below

```
usort($array,function($a,$b){
if($a->position == $b->position )
    return $a->point < $b->point;
else
    return $a->position < $b->position;
});
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys..@sam the code you sent is arranging by position but not doing sorting on the basis of 'point' I want to sort on the basis of point 'descending'

Comment: run the above function i have written, it first checks for the point if points are equal, it sorts using postion, else it sorts using point, which is default, i suggest you to run it in your php script, i have run it and showing perfect result

Comment: I want to sort first on the basis of position and then for those position the points will be in DESC order. I hope it make sense